# Not able to set value to dropdown(developed using angular js) using selenium C#

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, selenium

Every time I select a value in dropdown a new set of code is generating for its values.

```
<div class='k-li-stscroller'>
<ui id='prdtype_listbox>
<li data-offset-index="0">Test0</li>
<li data-offset-index="0">Test1</li>
<li data-offset-index="0">Test2</li>
<li data-offset-index="0">Test3</li>
<li data-offset-index="0">Test4</li>
 </ui>
 </div>

 <div class='k-li-stscroller'>
 <ui id='prdtype_listbox>
 <li data-offset-index="0">Test0</li>
 <li data-offset-index="0">Test1</li>
 <li data-offset-index="0">Test2</li>
 <li data-offset-index="0">Test3</li>
 <li data-offset-index="0">Test4</li>
 </ui>
  </div>
     ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> prd =      driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='k-list-scroller']/ul[@id='prdtype_listbox']"));
     ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> ListVal=prd[0].FindElements(By.XPath("*"));

 foreach (var lst in ListVal)
 {

     string liText = lst.text();
     if (liText.Equals("Test1"))
     {
      lst.click();
       break;
     }
  }
```

It select the Test1 but then selects the default value once again.
How to set the selected value.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to properly format the HTML and code. Also separate the HTML from the code so that it's easier to follow.

Comment: Is the HTML listed twice for some reason? Both examples look exactly the same.

Comment: the HTML code is listed twice to explain that its generating multiple times

Comment: I have a dropdown which is not a select, now every time I select the value , the div is generating. because of which I m not able to set the value. its selecting the given value and then again selects the default value.

Comment: Can you link the page? Have you tried the code I posted below? It should work.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a dropdown that isn't a `SELECT`, you generally want to click the dropdown once to open it then click the desired element that has been exposed in the list. I would write a function for something like this so it can be reused.

```
public void SetValue(string value)
{
    IWebElement dropdown = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("prdtype_listbox"));
    dropdown.Click();
    dropdown.FindElement(By.XPath($".//li[.='{value}']")).Click();
}
```